# How to create a page in Orchard core cms (orchard 2) I know to how to create with Orchard 1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, orchardcms

is there a good reference to know how to make this in orchard 2 
I searched but I didn't find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Orchard core works quite similar to Orchard 1. Also I found the Templates that come with Orchard core quite helpful. Documentation exists at https://orchardcore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.
My finding is that although Orchard core works quite well and stable, Templating is not so easy :)

Have fun